# Como faço para colocar uma imagem no Itextsharp?

Tags: c#, imagem, itextsharp

Estou tentando colocar uma imagem no pdf, porem da erro pois a classe Image do ItextSharp  só aceita Uri, e o que eu tenho é uma stream recebida que ja converti para System.Drawing.Image.

```
 public static Document GeraPdf(Stream stream)
    {
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        doc.SetMargins(40, 40, 40, 80);
        doc.AddCreationDate();

        string caminho = @"C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\eae.pdf";

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(caminho, FileMode.Create));

        doc.Open();

        string dados = "";
        System.Drawing.Image img1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);

       Image ImagemPdf= Image.GetInstance(img1,ImageFormat.Jpeg);//Aqui esta o Erro


        Paragraph paragrafo = new Paragraph(dados, new Font(Font.NORMAL, 14));

        paragrafo.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;

        paragrafo.Add("TESTE TESTE TESTE");

        doc.Add(paragrafo);

        doc.Close();
        return doc;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é apenas uma `URI`, você pode usar o próprio stream do parâmetro de input... mas o `System.Image.Image` não deveria dar erro (caso o mime esteja correto). Por fim reparei que você não adicionava a imagem ao documento.

```
   public static Document GeraPdf(Stream stream)
    {
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        doc.SetMargins(40, 40, 40, 80);
        doc.AddCreationDate();

        string caminho = @"C:\temp\eae.pdf";

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(caminho, FileMode.Create));

        doc.Open();

        string dados = "";       

        Image ImagemPdf = Image.GetInstance(stream);
        //Configura os atributos que achar pertinente;
        doc.Add(ImagemPdf);

        Paragraph paragrafo = new Paragraph(dados, new Font(Font.NORMAL, 14));

        paragrafo.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;

        paragrafo.Add("TESTE TESTE TESTE");        
        doc.Add(paragrafo);

        doc.Close();
        return doc;
    }
```